# Is there a selector that matches CNContactSortOrder.userDefault when using UILocalizedIndexedCollation to create section indexes in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build an app modeled off of iPhone's Contacts app.  When I fetch records from the CNContactStore. I can specify CNContactSortOrder.userDefault.

```
let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:
            [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])
fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault
```

I would like to replicate this sort order when creating section indexes. I can create a selector for CNContact.familyName.  I need something like .userDefault because it picks up other fields like nickname when familyName is nil and includes it in the sorted results correctly.

```
import UIKit
import Contacts

class SectionIndexesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()
    var sections: [[CNContact]] = []
    var sectionTitles: [String] = []
    var contacts: [CNContact] = [] {
        didSet {
            sectionTitles.removeAll()
            sections.removeAll()
//            let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: CNContact.familyName)
            let selector: Selector = #selector(getter:       CNContact.comparator(forNameSortOrder: .userDefault))
            var sectionsAll = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)
            let sortedContacts = collation.sortedArray(from: contacts, collationStringSelector: selector)
            for contact in sortedContacts {
                let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: contact, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sectionsAll[sectionNumber].append(contact as! CNContact)
            }
            for index in 0 ..< sectionsAll.count {
                if sectionsAll[index].count > 0 {
                    sectionTitles.append(collation.sectionTitles[index])
                    sections.append(sectionsAll[index] as! [CNContact])
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:
            [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])
        fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault
        let store = CNContactStore()
        do {
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) -> Void in
            self.contacts.append(contact)
            })
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TVCellSectionIndexes", for: indexPath)
        let contact = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
        cell.textLabel?.text = formatter.string(from: contact)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return collation.sectionIndexTitles
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        return collation.section(forSectionIndexTitle: index)     
    } 
}
```

The compile error I receive is: Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

How do I expose .userDefault to @objc?

[Apple's Contacts App with added records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXhci.png)

Comment: The error is because the selector needs to be for an object method, property or initializer. The `sortedArray` method then uses the selector on each member of the array. The documentation states `The method should take no arguments and return an NSString object.` However, `CNContact.comparator(forNameSortOrder: .userDefault)` returns a comparator which is a block that has the following signature: `(Any, Any) -> ComparisonResult`

Comment: Have a look at `CNContactsUserDefaults.shared().sortOrder`, that'll return the user setting and you can switch on that result to use either `.familyName` or `.givenName` and make a selector from that.

Comment: Okay that gives me what I sorted by.  That's not the problem I'm trying to solve.  The ``` fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault ``` sorts on a compound key. If you create some dummy contacts in the simulator with records that have only emailAddresses, givenName, nickname, phoneNumber.  Those fields get included in the sort even though familyName is nil.  How can I replicate that in creating section indexes?  I'm going to try to post an image of Apple's Contacts screen show with the type of data I'm describing.  (Not sure I know how to do that?)

Comment: See "Apple's Contacts App with added records" image for an example of how the app handles records without a familyName.

Comment: The only way I can think of that will accomplish this is to add my own sortKey based off of the hierarchy of data (familyName, givenName, middleName, nickname, OrganizationName, emailAddress, or if not any of the above then phoneNumber).  Then put the soreKey in a tuple with the CNContact and run that through the collation process.  I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to do this, because if I build my own I'm likely to miss something.